# Why can not convert to byte carriage return

Tags: c#

I test this code:

```
    string s = "\r";
    byte b = Convert.ToByte(s);
    Console.WriteLine(b);
    Console.ReadLine();
```

and i got an exception of type:

```
FormatException
```

Why is it happening?

Comment: Because `\r` is not a number... What behavior were you expecting?

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y57wwkzk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): "Converts the specified string representation of a **number**".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Convert.ToByte()` takes a string representation of a number (like "1") and reads it into a `byte`. If you want to get the value of `\r` (13):

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("\r")[0]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var c = '\r';  //Change to a char
var b = Convert.ToByte(s);
Console.WriteLine(b);
Console.ReadLine();  //Result 13
```

Comment: Oops looks like someone bet me to it

Comment: Different approach though. Interesting.

Comment: Much simpler: `var s = '\r'; var b = (byte) s;`

Comment: Can also just do: `(byte)'\r'`

Comment: I guess it's not entirely clear what the OP wants to accomplish :)

Comment: @JonB, i guess your answer is a pretty reasonably guess about what the OP wants...